# OS X Python vs QGIS Python?

Tags: pyqgis, installation, mac, osx

I'm wondering why after I updated to Python 2.7.6 on my OS X 10.9 Mac, QGIS Python console says that it is still running the old 2.7.5 version. This is not affecting my work but I'm curious about why this happens.

I though QGIS used the Python that comes with OS X but it seems it doesn't.

Do any of you know something about it?

I'm using KyngChaos QGIS 2.0.1 installers.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Can you add some more detail, such as how you installed 2.7.5 and how you installed 2.7.6? Please edit the question (just click edit above) to add this important detail.

Comment: as far as I know qgis uses its "own" python interpreter, so when you install a newer/other one on your os using a standard python-setup its not used by qgis (at least qgis running under windows)

Answer (score 2):

As Mac OS X is an Unix System, the QGIS version of KyngChaos does not uses its "own" interpreter (as in Windows) but one of the Apple Python versions pre-installed ( [What version(s) of Python are pre-installed on OSX 10.9 Mavericks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106125/what-versions-of-python-are-pre-installed-on-osx-10-9-mavericks)).

The QGIS version of Kyngchaos and the masters versions of Larry Shaffer ([Nightly Mac Build of QGIS from 'master' Branch](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/)) use the Apple Python version 2.7.5 ( as you write: "QGIS Python console says that it is still running the old 2.7.5 version") with modules in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

If you install another version of Python (from Python.org, with Homebrew, with MacPorts, with Anaconda,...), as your upgrade to 2.7.6, QGIS does not recognize it.