# How to install xlw and xlrd libraries on MacOS so that QGIS Python can see them?

Tags: qgis, python, mac

I experience a problem with XYtools and need to install Excel libraries for Python. I tried to install them directly from the terminal and it worked on the system, however, how to import them into QGIS?
This is how the error looks like:

```
import xlrd
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named xlrd
```

I tried to install them with pip:

```
python -m pip install xlwt==1.0.0
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): xlwt==1.0.0 in /Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt-1.0.0-py2.7.egg
```

When I try to export file as xls from QGIS, the same error persists:

```
There is a problem with loading a python module which is needed to read/write Excel files. Please see documentation/help how to install python xlw and xlrd libraries.
```

Comment: QGIS uses the Apple Python (in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages ) therefore simply install them in the classical Python way (easy_install, pip), see [OS X Python vs QGIS Python](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82759/os-x-python-vs-qgis-python/82773#82773)

Comment: It appears that you may currently have two accounts: http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/67208/natasha-love and http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/67202/ntm which is making for a difficult editing experience for you.  Please use [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts ASAP.  As a one-off I'll approve an edit by @NatashaLove.